# Mongo filter works inside the mongo shell but doesn't work when written in go

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

Mongo: 4.4
Go: 1.17.3

I'm trying to get documents with string field value longer than four symbols.
Here is the query I use inside mongo's shell:

```
db.player.find({
    "name": { "$exists": true },
        "$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$name" }, 4 ] } 
    })
```

And here is the same query but coded as `bson` filter in `go`:

```
longName := bson.M{
    "name": bson.M{"$exists": true},
    "$expr": bson.M{
        "$gt": bson.A{
            bson.M{"$strLenCP": "$name"},
            4,
        },
    },
}
```

```
fmc, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), longName)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
var longBoi models.Player
err = fmc.Decode(&longBoi)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err) 
    // panic here: 
    // 2021/12/15 15:53:46 EOF
    // panic: EOF
}
```

The first will output desired documents with string field value length longer than certain number. The second will error with just `EOF`, timestamp and callstack. Debugger says that `batch` inside coursor `fmc` contains no data.

What's wrong in the second case?

Comment: `Find()` returns an array of documents. Unmarshal into a value of `[]models.Player`, not a single `models.Player`.

Comment: @icza `2021/12/15 16:27:17 cannot decode document into []models.Player` unfortunately. This error wasn't present before.

Comment: `Find()` returns a `Cursor()`, not the result documents. You have to call `All()` on the cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fixes the problem:

```
var longBoi []models.Player
err = fmc.All(context.TODO(), &longBoi)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
```

`Find()` returns the `Cursor()`, not the documents. The cursor then can be used to iterate over documents matching the filter by calling `All()` or some other method.